# linear programming in python?

Tags: python, linear-programming

I need to make a linear programming model. Here are the inequalities I'm using (for example):

```
6x + 4y <= 24
x + 2y <= 6
-x + y <= 1
y <= 2
```

I need to find the area described by these inequalities, and shade it in a graph, as well as keep track of the vertices of the bounding lines of this area, and draw the bounding line in a different color. See the graph below for an example of what I'm looking for.

[image: image of the points of intersection].

I'm using Python 3.2, numpy, and matplotlib. Are there better modules for linear programming in Python?

Comment: Step one convert the system of inequalities into matrix form.

Comment: @izomorphius according to wikipedia, linear programming is mathematical optimization: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming

Comment: @möter agreed -removing my comment. The mistake is mine not the Op's

Comment: Your third equation, `-x + x <= 1` is a no-op, since it simplifies to `0 <= 1`, which is true for all x and y.

Comment: @user24562 Could you please also elaborate the process that you have used for your default code. (using numpy & matplotlib)

Comment: @user24562 : Here is a detailed step-by-step example using PuLP. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33160262/linear-programming-simplex-lp-pulp

Answer (score 74, accepted):

**UPDATE:** The answer has become somewhat outdated in the past 4 years,
here is an update. You have many options:

- If you do not *have to* do it Python then it is a lot more easier to
  do  this in a **modeling langage**, see [Any good tools to solve
  integer programs on linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10668020/341970)
- I personally use **[Gurobi](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/)** these
  days through its Python API. It is a commercial, closed-source
  product but free for academic research.
- With **[PuLP](https://pypi.org/project/PuLP/)** you can create [MPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPS_%28format%29) and [LP files](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.1/lp-format.htm) and then
  solve them with  GLPK, COIN CLP/CBC, CPLEX, or XPRESS through their
  command-line  interface. This approach has its advantages and
  disadvantages.
- The **[OR-Tools from Google](https://developers.google.com/optimization)** is an open source software suite for optimization, tuned for tackling the world's toughest problems in vehicle routing, flows, integer and linear programming, and constraint programming.
- **[Pyomo](https://www.pyomo.org/)** is a Python-based, open-source optimization modeling language with a diverse set of optimization capabilities.
- SciPy offers linear programming: **[scipy.optimize.linprog](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html).** (I have
  never tried this one.)
- Apparently, **[CVXOPT](https://cvxopt.org)** offers a [Python interface to GLPK](https://cvxopt.org/install/index.html#standard-installation), I did
  not know that. I have been using [GLPK](https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/glpk.html) for 8 years now and I can
  highly recommend GLPK. The [examples and tutorial of CVXOPT](https://cvxopt.org/examples/index.html) seem really nice!
- You can find other possibilites at in the Wikibook under
  **[GLPK/Python](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLPK/Python).** Note that many of these are not necessarily resticted
  to GLPK.

Comment: use PuLP, its an awesome python interface for GLPK, CPLEX or Gurobi

Comment: Anonymous downvotes aren't helping anybody. What is wrong with the answer?

Comment: [Version 1.1 of PuLP](https://pypi.org/project/PuLP/1.1/) links to a homepage at jeannot.org that my Sophos blocks with "High Risk Website Blocked, Access has been blocked as the threat C2/Generic-A has been found on this website." Sophos's [page](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/threat-center/threat-analyses/viruses-and-spyware/C2~Generic-A.aspx) says it's "Command and Control malware." Has anyone used PuLP? What is your take on this?

Comment: @mmorin Thank you, I accepted your edit. It's good to see that people find this answer useful.

Comment: I think PuLP should be on top of this list, followed by Google ortools and Pyomo

Comment: @Evgeny Thanks, added those too, and updated the links as well. I appreaciate your feedback

Answer (score 20):

I'd recommend the package [cvxopt](https://cvxopt.org/) for solving convex optimization problems in Python. A short example with Python code for a linear program is in cvxopt's documentation [here](https://cvxopt.org/examples/tutorial/lp.html).

Answer (score 7):

The other answers have done a good job providing a list of solvers.  However, only PuLP has been mentioned as a Python library to formulating LP models.

Another great option is [Pyomo](http://www.pyomo.org/). Like PuLP, you can send the problem to any solver and read the solution back into Python.  You can also manipulate solver parameters.  A classmate and I compared the performance of PuLP and Pyomo back in 2015 and we found Pyomo could generate .LP files for the same problem several times more quickly than PuLP.

Answer (score 6):

The only time a graph is used to solve a linear program is for a homework problem.  In all other cases, linear programming problems are solved through matrix linear algebra.

As for Python, while there are some pure-Python libraries, most people use a native library with Python bindings.  There is a wide variety of free and commercial libraries for linear programming.  For a detailed list, see [Linear Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Solvers_and_scripting_.28programming.29_languages) in Wikipedia or the [Linear Programming Software Survey](http://www.informs.org/ORMS-Today/Public-Articles/June-Volume-38-Number-3/Software-Survey-Linear-Programming) in OR/MS Today.

Disclaimer: I currently work for Gurobi Optimization and formerly worked for ILOG, which provided CPLEX.

Comment: Between homework and work there's also passion for learning - I think the first sentence you wrote is out of place...

Comment: Which is the fastest for Linear Programming Problems?

Answer (score 4):

For solving the linear programming problem, you can use the [scipy.optimize.linprog](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html#scipy.optimize.linprog) module in SciPy, which uses the Simplex algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a graphical representation of the problem, inspired from [How to visualize feasible region for linear programming (with arbitrary inequalities) in Numpy/MatplotLib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57017444/how-to-visualize-feasible-region-for-linear-programming-with-arbitrary-inequali)

[image: Linear Programming]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = np.linspace(0,5,200)
x,y = np.meshgrid(m,m)
plt.imshow(((6*x+4*y<=24)&(x+2*y<=6)&(-x+y<=1)&(y<=2)&(x>=0)&(y>=0)).astype(int), 
    extent=(x.min(),x.max(),y.min(),y.max()),origin='lower',cmap='Greys',alpha=0.3);
# plot constraints
x = np.linspace(0, 5, 2000)
# 6*x+4*y<=24
y0 = 6-1.5*x
# x+2*y<=6
y1 = 3-0.5*x
# -x+y<=1
y2 = 1+x
# y <= 2
y3 = (x*0) + 2
# x >= 0
y4 = x*0
plt.plot(x, y0, label=r'$6x+4y\leq24$')
plt.plot(x, y1, label=r'$x+2y\leq6$')
plt.plot(x, y2, label=r'$-x+y\leq1$')
plt.plot(x, 2*np.ones_like(x), label=r'$y\leq2$')
plt.plot(x, y4, label=r'$x\geq0$')
plt.plot([0,0],[0,3], label=r'$y\geq0$')
xv = [0,0,1,2,3,4,0]; yv = [0,1,2,2,1.5,0,0]
plt.plot(xv,yv,'ko--',markersize=7,linewidth=2)
for i in range(len(xv)):
    plt.text(xv[i]+0.1,yv[i]+0.1,f'({xv[i]},{yv[i]})')
plt.xlim(0,5); plt.ylim(0,3); plt.grid(); plt.tight_layout()
plt.legend(loc=1); plt.xlabel('x'); plt.ylabel('y')
plt.show()
```

The problem is missing an objective function so any of the shaded points satisfy the inequalities. If it did have an objective function (e.g. `Maximize x+y`) then many capable Python solvers can handle this problem. Here is a Linear Programming example in [GEKKO](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that also supports mixed integer, nonlinear, and differential constraints.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
x,y = m.Array(m.Var,2,lb=0)
m.Equations([6*x+4*y<=24,x+2*y<=6,-x+y<=1,y<=2])
m.Maximize(x+y)
m.solve(disp=False)
```

Large scale LP problems are solved in matrix form or in sparse matrix form where only the non-zeros of the matrices are stored. There is a [tutorial on LP solutions](https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/LinearProgramming) with a few examples that I developed for a university course.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the [PuLP](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PuLP/1.1) python package. It has a nice interface and you can use differenty types of algorithms to solve LP.

Answer (score 0):

lpsolve is the easiest to me. No need to install separate solver. It comes with in the package.