# Linear Programming (Simplex LP) PuLP?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, linear-programming, pulp

In Python only, and using data from a Pandas dataframe, how can I use [PuLP](http://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/CaseStudies/a_blending_problem.html) to solve linear programming problems the same way I can in Excel? How much budget should be allocated to each Channel under the New Budget column so we maximize the total number of estimated successes? I'm really looking for a concrete **example** using data from a dataframe and not really high-level advice.

**Problem Data Setup**

```
    Channel  30-day Cost  Trials  Success  Cost Min  Cost Max  New Budget
0  Channel1      1765.21    9865      812    882.61   2647.82           0
1  Channel2      2700.00   15000      900   1350.00   4050.00           0
2  Channel3      2160.00   12000      333   1080.00   3240.00           0
```

This is a **Maximization** problem.

The *objective function* is:

```
objective_function = sum((df['New Budget']/(df['30-day Cost']/df['Trials']))*(df['Success']/df['Trials']))
```

The *constraints* are:

1. The sum of `df['New Budget']` must equal `5000`
2. The `New Budget` for a given channel can go no *lower* than the `Cost Min`
3. The `New Budget` for a given channel can go no *higher* than the `Cost Max`

Any ideas how to translate this pandas dataframe solver linear problem using PuLP or any other solver approach? The end-result would be what you see in the image below.

[image: Desired result]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general you create a dictionary of variables (`x` in this case) and a model variable (`mod` in this case). To create the objective you use `sum` over the variables times some scalars, adding that result to `mod`. You construct constraints by again computing linear combinations of variables, using `>=`, `<=`, or `==`, and adding that constraint to `mod`. Finally you use `mod.solve()` to get the solutions.

```
import pulp

# Create variables and model
x = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("x", df.index, lowBound=0)
mod = pulp.LpProblem("Budget", pulp.LpMaximize)

# Objective function
objvals = {idx: (1.0/(df['30-day Cost'][idx]/df['Trials'][idx]))*(df['Success'][idx]/float(df['Trials'][idx])) for idx in df.index}
mod += sum([x[idx]*objvals[idx] for idx in df.index])

# Lower and upper bounds:
for idx in df.index:
    mod += x[idx] >= df['Cost Min'][idx]
    mod += x[idx] <= df['Cost Max'][idx]

# Budget sum
mod += sum([x[idx] for idx in df.index]) == 5000.0

# Solve model
mod.solve()

# Output solution
for idx in df.index:
    print idx, x[idx].value()
# 0 2570.0
# 1 1350.0
# 2 1080.0

print 'Objective', pulp.value(mod.objective)
# Objective 1798.70495012
```

Data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
idx = [0, 1, 2]
d = {'channel': pd.Series(['Channel1', 'Channel2', 'Channel3'], index=idx),
     '30-day Cost': pd.Series([1765.21, 2700., 2160.], index=idx),
     'Trials': pd.Series([9865, 1500, 1200], index=idx),
     'Success': pd.Series([812, 900, 333], index=idx),
     'Cost Min': pd.Series([882.61, 1350.00, 1080.00], index=idx),
     'Cost Max': pd.Series([2647.82, 4050.00, 3240.00], index=idx)}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df
#    30-day Cost  Cost Max  Cost Min  Success  Trials   channel
# 0      1765.21   2647.82    882.61      812    9865  Channel1
# 1      2700.00   4050.00   1350.00      900    1500  Channel2
# 2      2160.00   3240.00   1080.00      333    1200  Channel3
```

Comment: In the same example what if I have two variables. For eg: currently, $G$2:$G$4 is there if want something like $G$2:$H$6 as changing the variable in pulp.

Comment: @josliber, I'm curious, why are you using `1.0` in your objective function where OP is using `df['New Budget']`? Is that because `df['New Budget']` are the variable cells? I'm trying to map this to my own problem but can't figure out where to put my variable cells. Thanks!

Comment: @tmthyjames I am using `1.0/(df['30-day Cost'][idx]/df['Trials'][idx]))*(df['Success'][idx]/float(df['Trials'][idx])` because this is the OP's objective function from their excel spreadsheet. If you have a different formula then you would use that instead.