# How to solve AX = B equation with Python (NumPy, SciPy etc.), where A, X, B are matrices and all elements of X must be non-negative

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-equation

I need to solve an equation AX = B using Python where A, X, B are matrices and all values of X must be non-negative.

The best solution I've found is

```
X = np.linalg.lstsq(A, B, rcond=None)
```

but as a result X contains negative values. Is it possible to get a solution without negative values? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.lsq_linear.html#scipy.optimize.lsq_linear

Comment: @user2699 `B` has to be one-dimensional with `scipy.optimize.lsq_linear` and `scipy.optimize.nnls` unfortunately.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697995/linear-programming-in-python

Comment: @user2653663 Why is that an issue?  A wrapper can easily solve for each column in B, which reference solution in the question using `np.linalg.lstsq` already does.

Answer (score 6):

In general, this is not mathematically possible.  Given the basic requirements of `A` and `B` being invertible, `X` is a unique matrix.  If you don't like the elements that `X` has, you can't simply ask for another solution: there isn't one.  You'll have to change `A` or `B` to get a different result.

Comment: A and B do not have to be invertible - that is not a constraint given in the question or even implied.  The least squares solver given in the question finds the solution that gives the minimum mean squared error  - but there are other definitions of error (or constraints on B) that result in unique solutions for non-invertible A.

Answer (score 2):

You could solve it with `cvxpy`:

```
import cvxpy

def solve(A, B):
    """
    Minimizes |AX - B|**2, assuming A and B are 
    square matrices for simplicity. If this optimized 
    error is zero, this corresponds to solving AX = B.
    """
    n = A.shape[0]
    X = cvxpy.Variable((n,n))
    # Set objective
    obj_fun = cvxpy.sum_squares(A*X - B)
    objective = cvxpy.Minimize(obj_fun)
    # Set constraints
    constraints = [X >= 0]
    prob = cvxpy.Problem(objective, constraints)
    result = prob.solve(solver = "ECOS")
    return X.value
```

EDIT: The answer by [Prune](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56228106/2653663) is correct I believe. You can check if the error in the numerical solver is non-zero by inspecting `results`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I got "'shape' elements cannot be negative" error with A.shape=(128,1025) and B.shape=(128,146). When I tried the solution on arrays with less dimensios, it works fine.