# How to visualize feasible region for linear programming (with arbitrary inequalities) in Numpy/MatplotLib?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, linear-programming

I need to implement a solver for linear programming problems. All of  the restrictions are <= ones such as

5x + 10y <= 10

There can be an arbitrary amount of these restrictions. Also , x>=0 y>=0 implicitly.

I need to find the optimal solutions(max) and show the feasible region in matplotlib. I've found the optimal solution by implementing the simplex method but I can't figure out how to draw the graph.

Some approaches I've found:

1. [This link](http://benalexkeen.com/linear-programming-with-python-and-pulp-part-1/) finds the minimum of the y points from each function and uses plt.fillBetween() to draw the region. But it doesn't work when I change the order of the equations. I'm not sure which y values to minimize(). So I can't use it for arbitrary restrictions.
2. Find solution for every pair of restrictions and draw a polygon. Not efficient.

Answer (score 18):

An easier approach might be to have matplotlib compute the feasible region on its own (with you only providing the constraints) and then simply overlay the "constraint" lines on top.

```
# plot the feasible region
d = np.linspace(-2,16,300)
x,y = np.meshgrid(d,d)
plt.imshow( ((y>=2) & (2*y<=25-x) & (4*y>=2*x-8) & (y<=2*x-5)).astype(int) , 
                extent=(x.min(),x.max(),y.min(),y.max()),origin="lower", cmap="Greys", alpha = 0.3);


# plot the lines defining the constraints
x = np.linspace(0, 16, 2000)
# y >= 2
y1 = (x*0) + 2
# 2y <= 25 - x
y2 = (25-x)/2.0
# 4y >= 2x - 8 
y3 = (2*x-8)/4.0
# y <= 2x - 5 
y4 = 2 * x -5

# Make plot
plt.plot(x, 2*np.ones_like(y1))
plt.plot(x, y2, label=r'$2y\leq25-x$')
plt.plot(x, y3, label=r'$4y\geq 2x - 8$')
plt.plot(x, y4, label=r'$y\leq 2x-5$')
plt.xlim(0,16)
plt.ylim(0,11)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
plt.xlabel(r'$x$')
plt.ylabel(r'$y$')
```

[image]

Comment: I a total noob when it comes to these things so I hope you don't mind the questions. I haven't used any sort of casting in python. Is the .asType() for generating an array of 0s and ones based on whether the point follows the restrictions?

Comment: @Arturo If you evaluate the inequalities, you will see that python (actually, nympy) returns an array with `True`/`False` entries that `plt.imshow` does not understand. With `.astype(int)`, the entries are translated to `0`/`1`'s that `imshow` understands.

Comment: I'm aware `np` comes from numpy, but where would I get `plt`?

Comment: @Lori `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Answer (score 3):

This is a vertex enumeration problem. You can use the function lineqs which visualizes the system of inequalities A x >= b for any number of lines. The function will also display the vertices on which the graph was plotted.

The last 2 lines mean that x,y >=0

```
from intvalpy import lineqs
import numpy as np

A = -np.array([[5, 10],
               [-1, 0],
               [0, -1]])
b = -np.array([10, 0, 0])

lineqs(A, b, title='Solution', color='gray', alpha=0.5, s=10, size=(15,15), save=False, show=True)
```

[image: Visual Solution]

[Visual Solution Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAPiY.png)

Answer (score 0):

I created a Jupyter notebook example with UI sliders imported from `ipywidgets`, that allows the user to try various "what-if" scenarios.

GitHub: https://github.com/jbonfardeci/linear-programming

Google Colab notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1NLV0RsZdRUUDbd-_OCkqCAjZEXA3UwKW?usp=sharing

[image: Visually Solve Linear Programming Problem]

Comment: Those wishing to try this as an active Jupyter `.ipynb` file can click [here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/fomightez/communication_voila/master?urlpath=git-pull%3Frepo%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fgithub.com%252Fjbonfardeci%252Flinear-optimization%26urlpath%3Ddoc%252Ftree%252Flinear-optimization%252Fexample.ipynb%26branch%3Dmain) to get a session right in your browser served via the MyBinder service with **all the necessary packages already installed and working so you can just go ahead and do '`Run`' >  '`Run All Cells`' to try it out**.

Comment: I updated the link to a notebook in Google Colab.